# In what order are objects initialized when mixing pointers and non-pointer objects?

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization

Take the following code:

```
Foo *foo = fooFactory();
Bar bar(foo);
```

I have three questions:

1. Is this safe? In other words, am I guaranteed that `fooFactory()` will be called and `foo` initialized before `Bar`'s constructor is run (assuming `fooFactory()` doesn't throw)?
2. Does the answer to question #1 change if this is part of a function, part of a class, or just a bare declaration outside any blocks?
3. Does the answer change if `Bar`'s constructor doesn't actually take a `Foo` pointer, but references the `foo` variable directly?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Keeping it simple: statements are executed in sequence.

Comment: But only when the order matters. If it doesn't the compiler is free to play whatever games produce a more efficient program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ (and C), statements execute (or appear to execute) in the order they appear in the source code.  Under the as-if rule, out-of-order execution may occur when statement B has no dependencies on statement A in order to improve performance.  Thus, given:

```
int i = 1;
int j = 2;
int k = i + j;
```

The first two statements might be executed out of order, but the third must not be.  (Of course, in real life, simple statements like this are often optimised out, but you get the idea).

So, in the code you posted, the second statement uses the result of the first, so the statements will be executed in order.

Comment: [Documentation on the As-If Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, it's safe and works as expected
2. No, the order doesn't change. It could only change in a member initializer list in a constructor (but that's a different syntax).
3. No, that also doesn't change the answer.